# Why is methamphetamine less polar then amphetamine?

Tags: polarity, chromatography

The question is as stated in the title. Is there a general way to determine relative polarity of organic compounds?
This question is for use in the context of the manner in which polarity of the components of the mobile phase in high-performance liquid chromatography determine the polarity of the stationary phase.

Comment: Hydrocarbons are not polar. Some other organic compounds are, though.

Comment: Oh is there a method to determine which organic compounds are going to be more or less polar? I'm trying to reconcile an answer in the back of my workbook with my pretty limited understanding at the moment.

Comment: Yes, anything from quantum chemical calculations (which you might not understand) to pretty simplistic rules which I would argue are sufficient in this case ( something something electronegativity). You should maybe consider starting at simpler molecules, you know, at the beginning.

Comment: Yea, I'm asking about this as a year 12 chemistry student and am fairly certain we have not encountered quantum chemical calculations yet (but they do sound fascinating). Do you have any examples of simpler molecules for which I could apply a fairly defined process to, in order to determine their relative polarities?

Comment: @Kcronix I don't think the comment section below your question is the place to discuss this. Have you considered a google search?

Comment: Yes I have, I was wondering if anyone could summarise the process for the specific case mentioned

Comment: You took a pair in which is particularly difficult to offer a simple rule as for the two are relatively similar and not particularly polar. Not a classic example...